# grails Radio Button True or false checked property

Tags: grails, radio-button, gsp

I have radio group with two values. On editing a record, the radio should be set to checked or unchecked depending on the value from database.I use

```
    <input type="radio" name="value1" value="${someValue}" ${it.id == true ?'checked="checked"' : ''}>                         
     <input type="radio" name="value1" value="${someValue}" ${it.id == false ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}>
```

Using such code, gives me syntax error. Please correct my syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use:

```
<g:radio name="value1" value="${someValue}" checked="${it.id}" />
```

(assuming `it.id` is a boolean as you seem to say)

Comment: Using this checked="true" or "false" either way checks the box. even if it has "false" value it checks.

Comment: Yeah, it should be `checked="${true}"` or `checked="${false}"`

Comment: I tried using checked= "${true}" or ${false} but even though the value is false, when I inspect in browser, I get both the radio as checked="checked"

Comment: you can also make comparison:


  `<g:radio name="value1" value="${someValue}" checked="${it.id == 1}" />`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to go this lengthy way. (assuming `it.id` yields a boolean)

```
<g:if test="${it.id}"> 
    <g:radio name="value1" value="${someValue}" checked="${it.id}" />
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:radio name="value1" value="${someValue}" />
</g:else>
```

You can use html `input` instead of `g:radio` in this case as well.

Comment: the method you suggested works! But there should be something more efficient.Thanks much!

Comment: Oddly, the version I suggested seems to work for me -- at least it does with 2.3.6

Comment: @tim_yates I know [what is happening](http://pastebin.com/ztGn8ajU). I did not test before leaving office, but now I did. I highly doubt OP is using it in the wrong way shown in the sample code. OP has to rectify that and accept your answer instead.

Comment: @user1610812 Have a look at the [sample code](http://pastebin.com/ztGn8ajU) and clarify if you are doing it the wrong way? If you are then you should accept tim's answer, it works that way. Make sure the checked flag in the model in a boolean true/false instead of a String true/false.

Comment: @tim_yates dmahapatro Yes from the sample code I do it wrong way. But the code that you showed also seems to be working. I will accept tim's answer. Thank you